# MySQL Select the next lower number but max 10%

Tags: mysql

i want to get the next Lower Number in a Select.
I found that, that is working.

But i need to say only when difference between i search and i get is 10%

```
SELECT *
FROM items
WHERE price <= my_price
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM items
WHERE price < my_price
  and price >= (my_price * 0.9)
```

Comment: That is working? I dont want to get over the my_price, only under, but max 10%

Comment: Sure. Did you not try it?